# Resize an uploaded requested image by flask

Tags: python, flask, python-imaging-library

I made an image request system on Flask by web browser, but I would like to resize this image and save them. I tried several things, and I could to do this. Using this code:

```
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS
          
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_image():                       
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        flash('No file part')
        #return redirect(request.url)
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No image selected for uploading')
        #return redirect(request.url)
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'foto.jpeg')) # Save first time

        #### Resize
        basewidth = 400
        foo = Image.open('./static/foto.jpeg') #Open 
        wpercent = (basewidth/float(foo.size[0]))
        hsize = int((float(foo.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
        foo = foo.resize((basewidth,hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        foo = ImageOps.exif_transpose(foo)
        foo.save("./static/fase1/foto.jpeg",optimize=True,quality=95) # Save second time
```

but it's not a smart way to do this, because I need to save the image, and open the image, resize then and save the image again. Some suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

If you have saved the image that was POST-ed to your Flask backend already, then you can do this:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('foo.jpg') # Open image
img = img.resize((150, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS) # Resize image
img.save('foo.jpg', format='JPEG') # Save resized image
```

`img.resize()` will return a resized copy of the original image, so do not forget to do `img = img.resize()` and not only `img.resize()` because it will not get saved.

Comment: I wold like save just one time. Can be, save directly and resized.

Comment: Than you can just `Image.open()` the image directly in Flask, without saving it to disk. Then do your modifications and then save.